# How to forward the logs if all the logs of a file is in single line?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

I am facing some trouble to forward the logs from rsyslog to logstash i wrote this grok filter but it is not working.maybe the problem is that, server is writing the all logs in a single line.

```
(?<AUDIt_LOG>[(0-9A-U]{0,4})(?<DATE>[0-9A-F]{8})%{INT:Log_Code}(?<Type>[a-zA-Z]{0,5})%{NOTSPACE:ServiceName} %{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE:Host} %{SPACE} %{WORD:Bank}&&%{WORD:BANK2}%{SPACE} %{WORD:USERNAME}
```

please follow this link for sample log.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx8yrs4bWFFjTFlpTkJhTl9SMHM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have each log per line for sure. Also you could use the Grok debugger to make sure that logs get parsed properly.

[Grok debugger on Heroku](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com)

Comment: Is there an any way to break the logs in next line?(Using bash Script or any thing else)

Comment: This is the server's responsibility (to write one log per line or using a well-defined separator instead of "\n")